# Displaying profile badge in Stack Exchange profile

Tags: support, profile-page, flair

I tried searching in Meta and other places, but I am not able to find how I could display a profile badge in my Stack Exchange profile? A preview of that is:

> [image]

Comment: On your profile page, near 'privileges', you can see 'flair', click on that and read the instructions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is called *flair*. It's simply an image, you can get info by going to the flair tab on your profile. The examples are HTML, but it's easy to convert them to markdown. Put one of these in your profile:

```
![](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/462627.png)
![](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/210807.png)
```

They render as:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh Wow... Thanks! That was simple! I should have known the right word! :D

Comment: You can use the HTML version also, that's what i have.